# Facing Error like, TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNAlarmNotification.sendNotification') in react-native-alarm-notification

Tags: react-native

I am creating an alarm app for **Android** in react-native. Therefore, I used the **react-native-alarm-notification** package. when i scheduling alarm i am getting **error** like,

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'RNAlarmNotification.sendNotification') in
> react-native-alarm-notification.

Also, follow the given solution to resolve the above error in package setup, but get the same error.

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Platform,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactNativeAN from 'react-native-alarm-notification';

const {RNAlarmNotification} = NativeModules;
const RNEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(RNAlarmNotification);

const alarmNotifData = {
  title: 'Alarm',
  message: 'Stand up',
  vibrate: true,
  play_sound: true,
  schedule_type: 'once',
  channel: 'wakeup',
  data: {content: 'my notification id is 22'},
  loop_sound: true,
  has_button: true,
};

const TestAlarm = () => {
  const [fireDate, setfireDate] = useState();
  const [update, setupdate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    subcription();
    // const _seconds = parseInt(0, 10);
    setfireDate(ReactNativeAN.parseDate(new Date(Date.now())));
  }, []);

  const subcription = () => {
    const _subscribeDismiss = RNEmitter.addListener(
      'OnNotificationDismissed',
      data => {
        const obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(`notification id: ${obj.id} dismissed`);
      },
    );
    const _subscribeOpen = RNEmitter.addListener(
      'OnNotificationOpened',
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        const obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(`app opened by notification: ${obj.id}`);
      },
    );
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      showPermissions();
      ReactNativeAN.requestPermissions({
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      }).then(
        data => {
          console.log('RnAlarmNotification.requestPermissions', data);
        },
        data => {
          console.log('RnAlarmNotification.requestPermissions failed', data);
        },
      );
    }
    return () => {
      _subscribeDismiss.remove();
      _subscribeOpen.remove();
    };
  };

  const showPermissions = () => {
    ReactNativeAN.checkPermissions(permissions => {
      console.log("permissions", permissions);
    });
  };

  console.log("fireDate11", fireDate)

  const AddAlarm = async () => {
    const details = {
      ...alarmNotifData,
      fire_date: fireDate,
      sound_name: 'iphone_ringtone.mp3',
    };
    console.log(`fireDate22 ${fireDate}`);
    console.log(`details ${fireDate}`);

    try {
      const alarm = await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm(details);
      console.log('AlarmCalled', alarm);
      if (alarm) {
        setupdate([...update, {date: `alarm set: ${fireDate}`, id: alarm.id}]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ErrorCalled', e);
    }
  };

  console.log('fireDate', fireDate);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>TestAlarm</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.date}
        onChangeText={text => setfireDate(text)}
        value={fireDate}
      />
      <Button title="Set Alarm" onPress={() => AddAlarm(fireDate)} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default TestAlarm;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  date: {height: 40, width: 300, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1},
});
```